# dual meaning of whereas

Tags: etymology

There are two well-known meanings of "whereas", which are roughly "given that" (legal) and "in contrast to" (common).  The [Douglas Harper, Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/whereas) only addresses the legal usage, which appears to be old. If that is the original usage, where did the now common usage come from?  (Perhaps as a replacement of [whyle as](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399095/usage-of-whileas-instead-of-whereas/399097)?)

Comment: The legal sense can be repeated: _Whereas, .... And whereas, ..._ The contrastive sense can't.  I think it is a metaphoric use of the legal sense in a non-legal context. First stipulate something with an expected outcome, then state a different outcome; just rhetoric.

Comment: Related: "Usage of whileas instead of whereas" https://english.stackexchange.com/q/399095/14666

Comment: "In **consideration of** the fact that" vs. "In **contrast to** the fact that". A bit of a bifurcation along the way very early on, I'd think.

Answer (score 2):

The OED has a citation for the (legalese) meaning of 'whereas', in the sense of 'in view of':

> (**1426-27**) W. Paston in Paston Lett. & Papers (2004) I. 10   *Where as* þe seyd
>   William Paston, by assignement and commaundement of þe seyd Duk of
>   Norffolk..was þe styward of þe seyd Duc of Norffolk.

An early citation for the usage 'in opposition to the principal clause in the sentence' is:

> (**1535**) Bible (Coverdale) 2 Esdras vii. 5   There are layed vp for vs
>   dwellynges of health & fredome, *where as* we haue lyued euell.

So it appears that both meanings obtained from fairly early on, and the latter use is not a modern development.

Comment: The Bible citation seems to mean just "where".

Comment: I don't think so: reading the entire passage suggests something like you're promising us healthy and free dwellings but we have been living wickedly? ([see here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8oFaAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA29-PA28&lpg=RA29-PA28&dq=There+are+laid+up+for+vs+dwellings+of+health+%26+freedom&source=bl&ots=70JumQCZTp&sig=ACfU3U3kH2D_mjbht768WW_vDyoQwRZpQA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGp4i94YzmAhXIQkEAHdIpDYYQ6AEwCXoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20laid%20up%20for%20vs%20dwellings%20of%20health%20%26%20freedom&f=false), for example.)

Comment: I don't see *wickedly*, though.

Comment: *Euell* is 'evil' ([see this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cgL5JO0hm9AC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=%22euell%22#v=onepage&q=%22euell%22&f=false)), hence 'wickedly'.

Comment: The first citation does not allow any interpretation, because it's missing the prior or later context (you might assume the usage is clear and I'm ignorant). The second interpretation might mean *wherupon*, that is, they were offered something, took it, and abused it, no? Suppose the OED confered with the source of the translation. Then the big question is, does the same ambiguity exist in Latin?